# Changing range of time series x-axis in the dttm format

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I would like to change the range in the X-axis of the time series but when I try it i get the following message: scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only.

I have tried:

```
t1<-read.csv("https://github.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries/blob/main/temp.csv")

months_order <- c(7:12,1:6)

dates <- make_datetime(c(rep(3,6), rep(4,6)), months_order)
t1 %>%
    
  mutate(datetime = make_datetime(year, month, day)) %>%
  
  filter(datetime >= make_datetime(2018,7), datetime < make_datetime(2020,7)) %>%
  
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(dummy = month(datetime) == 7 & datetime == min(datetime)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(dummy = cumsum(dummy)) %>%
  
  group_by(dummy) %>%
  mutate(datetime = datetime - years(year - 4) - years(month>=7),
         years = paste(unique(year), collapse = " / ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = datetime, y = T42, colour = years)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = dates, labels = month.abb[months_order]) +
  labs(colour = "Year")+scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2019-11-01","2020-04-30")))
```

I am looking only to plot only the winter months

I also tried adding `"%Y-%m-%d"` but I get the same result

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Missing is the definitions for `dates` and for `months_order`, and for `t0`.

Comment: You have two `scale_x_`, statements so only one (the first, I think) will be used.  Combine the contents of the two into one, i.e. `scale_x_datetime(breaks = ..., labels = ..., limits = ...)` and see if you get the required output.

Comment: Sorry, I added ````dates```` and ````months_order````.  T0 = T42 I changed it also

Comment: I tried ```` scale_x_datetime(limits=as.Date("2020-04-01","2020-10-01")) ```` and I can not get it to change